# SASS compile error not contain the parent selector &

Tags: css, sass

I got the following error while compile my bootstrap 4  sass

```
Error: Top-level selectors may not contain the parent selector "&".
```

Here's my code:

```
    @page {
  size: A4 portrait;
  margin: 1cm;
  font-size: $print-font-size-base !important;

  &:blank {
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

I'm thinking of removing the & and only leave it with `:blank {`
Is there other way of writing this SASS code to resolve the error?

Answer (score 1):

The css syntax for targeting a blank @page does contain a space before the pseudo-class:

```
@page :blank{
    /* css */
}
```

So removing the & will give you the correct formatting.

You can read more about the & in SASS and how it renders into CSS here:
[CSS Tricks - The Sass Ampersand](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/)